# Assign List of objects to ObservableCollection

Tags: c#, list, observablecollection

I have an ObservableCollection bound to a list box and a function that returns a list of objects like so:

```
private ObservableCollection<MyClass>    _myObservableCollection;

private static async Task<List<MyClass>> GetObjects()
{
    List<MyClass> objectList = new List<MyClass>();

    objectList.Add(blah blah); 
    objectList.Add(blah blah);

    return objectList;
}

// Call Function and add results to ObservableCollection
var objects = await GetObjects();

foreach (var ob in objects)
{
    _myObservableCollection.Add(ob);
}
```

Is there a simple way I can cast the results to the ObservableCollection unstead of looping round like I am doing?

I have tried the following but they do not work:

```
_myObservableCollection = await GetObjects() as ObservableCollection<MyClass>;

_myObservableCollection = objects as ObservableCollection<MyClass>;
```

Comment: Try ```new ObservableCollection<MyClass>(await GetObjects())```

Comment: my _myObservableCollection has already been newed in constructor

Comment: There are no other way to do that. You could create an extension method to do the foreach/add.

Comment: there is no way. even the constructor in `ObservableCollection` is copying the list. but that's the code you don't see.